# grep/sed/awk parsing text file to print multiple rows after a pattern matches and convert to one row

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am wanting to use grep/awk/sed to parse a text file containing various descriptions of several genes. I would like each row to represent a gene description.

Right now I am wanting to extract the Automated and Concise descriptions into single txt files each row representing the description for a single gene.

Download file

```
wget https://downloads.wormbase.org/releases/current-production-release/species/c_elegans/PRJNA13758/annotation/c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS283.functional_descriptions.txt.gz
```

I have been able to extract the desired text and have individual text files using the code below. However, I am unable to output the text into single rows.

```
awk '/Concise description:/{flag=1} flag; /Automated description/{flag=0}' c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS283.functional_descriptions.txt | grep -v "Automated description" > WB283_concise.txt

#do this for the next section automated description

awk '/Automated description:/{flag=1} flag; /Gene class description/{flag=0}' c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS283.functional_descriptions.txt | grep -v "Gene class description" > WB283_automated.txt

#I can also use sed
sed -ne '/Concise description:/,$ p' WB283_concise.txt > concise.txt
```

Can someone help?

Current text structure for 1 gene description

```
Concise description: aap-1 encodes the C. elegans ortholog of the phosphoinositide 
3-kinase (PI3K) p50/p55 adaptor/regulatory subunit; AAP-1 negatively regulates lifespan 
and dauer development, and likely functions as the sole adaptor subunit for the 
AGE-1/p110 PI3K catalytic subunit to which it binds in vitro; although AAP-1 potentiates 
insulin-like signaling, it is not absolutely required for insulin-like signaling 
under most conditions.
```

desired text structure for 1 gene description

```
Concise description: aap-1 encodes the C. elegans ortholog of the phosphoinositide 3-kinase (PI3K) p50/p55 adaptor/regulatory subunit; AAP-1 negatively regulates lifespan and dauer development, and likely functions as the sole adaptor subunit for the AGE-1/p110 PI3K catalytic subunit to which it binds in vitro; although AAP-1 potentiates insulin-like signaling, it is not absolutely required for insulin-like signaling under most conditions.
```

Thank you, Jose.

Comment: So, basically you just want to replace the line breaks by spaces, isnt't it? In this case, just pipe your multi-line output into `tr $'\n' ' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few small changes to OP's current `awk` code:

```
awk '
/Concise description:/  { flag=1; pfx="" }
/Automated description/ { flag=0; print "" }                # close out current printf line out output
flag                    { printf "%s%s",pfx,$0; pfx=" " }   # assuming appended lines are separated by a single space
' file
```

**NOTE:** I'm not sure I understand OP's current use of `grep -v` since we don't have a sample set of input that demonstrates the need for the `grep -v` ... ?

For the small sample provided this generates:

```
Concise description: aap-1 encodes the C. elegans ortholog of the phosphoinositide  3-kinase (PI3K) p50/p55 adaptor/regulatory subunit; AAP-1 negatively regulates lifespan  and dauer development, and likely functions as the sole adaptor subunit for the  AGE-1/p110 PI3K catalytic subunit to which it binds in vitro; although AAP-1 potentiates  insulin-like signaling, it is not absolutely required for insulin-like signaling  under most conditions.
```

---

Assumptions:

- OP needs to parse the input file twice (for two different blocks of text)
- the two different blocks of text do not overlap
- there may be multiple blocks of `Concise` or `Automated` text in the intput file, and all input is to be routed to one of two output files

We could consolidate OP's current 2x `awk` scripts into one, eg:

```
awk '
function close_line()    { if (outfile) print "" > outfile }      # close out prior printf line of output?

/Concise description:/   { close_line()
                           outfile="WB283_concise.txt"
                           pfx=""
                         }
/Automated description:/ { close_line()
                           outfile="WB283_automated.txt"
                           pfx=""
                         }
/Gene class description/ { close_line()
                           outfile=""
                         }
outfile                  { printf "%s%s", pfx, $0 > outfile
                           pfx=" "
                         }
END                      { close_line() }
' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The first code you advised worked well with the text file output I was wanting. I was using grep -v option to extract everything except "Automated description" which produced concise description only txt file. This is where I ran into issues.

Comment: My goal is to have a final txt file (data frame) organized so that each row represents a gene and each column is a description of the gene. Right now I just figured I would try extracting all the necessary columns individually.

Comment: @robledoj13 once you get your final code working, and if it consists of multiple scans of the input file, you may want to take another look at consolidating your code so that you only have to perform a single scan of the intput file ... doable but at this point not enough info in this particular question to address ... you'll want to ask a new question; for example, if you have a list of genes to process then said list could be placed into a 2nd file and a new `awk` script could (1st`) scan the list of genes/descriptions (and store in an array) and then (2nd) scan the main file once

Comment: Is there an easier way to extract the contents of the original file which contains block of text separated by equal sign into one text file with multiple rows and columns. Every row would be a gene and every column would include gene names (3), Concise description, automated description and gene class description? -long answer so I will probably make another post.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a slightly modified solution (not exactly what is asked for, but with potentially useful thoughts):

```
awk '
/WBGene/              { printf("\n%s: ", $2) }
/Concise description/ { flag = 1; $1=$2="" }
/=/                   { flag = 0 }
/^.* description/     { flag = 0 }
flag                  { printf " %s", $0 }
' c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS283.functional_descriptions.txt
```

The idea is to filter out the string "Concise description", as this is what we are looking for in any case. The name of the gene is printed in the first column, as many "Concise description's" don't include the name.

Output format is a single line for each gene, starting with its name (+ colon), followed by the "pure" concise description.

By the way: if you want to create a second output, with the "Automated description" in each line, change the second awk-line from `/Concise description/` to `/Automated description/`

Comment: I tried your code and it works very well. However, I am wanting to extract just the description without the WBGene. This does give me an idea to try and extract everything with one single code. As you can tell from the original file, I am wanting to have a data frame built so that every row would be a gene and every column would include gene names (3), Concise description, automated description and gene class description. -long answer so I will probably make another post soon.